# Range Min Query

Tags: arrays, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am having an array 2d array `A[n][k]` where `n,k<=1000`  and array `cost[n][n]` ,I am performing  an operation like this
( initially all element in `A` are `0` )

```
for(int i=1; i<=n; i++) {

   for(int j=0; j<min(k,i); j++) {

      int min = Max_Value;

      for(int r=0; r<i; r++) {
         min = min(min,A[r][j]+cost[r][i]);
      }
      A[i][j+1]=min
   }
}
```

Time complexity of my code is **O(N*K*N)** can i reduce it to **O(N*K*logN)** , I don't know how to use segment tree for this. For code you can see that it's dynamic programming.

Comment: 1) X, Y problem in your request makes it complicated to answer correctly. Please explain the meaning of your problem. At first glance you are looking for minimal distance in weighted graph. 2) If restrictions on cost are compatible with it, you can use Dijkstra algorithm.

Answer (score -1):

I guess something like this will work

Create a 2d Array `B[k][n]`

```
for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){

   for(int j=0;j<min(k,i);j++){

    int min =  Query(1,i-1,B[j]); // Min Value

    A[i][j+1] = min

    }

  for(int i=0;i<n;i++){

         update A[i] such that B[][i] gets updated   
}
}
```

Comment: This has also time complexity **O(NKN)** 1.Loop: n, 2. Loop: k 3.Loop: n